# Issue with Mouseover within Geographics

Tags: graphics, bugs

When using Graphics, I can change the color of the object with the use of Mouseover.

```
    Graphics[{Opacity[0.9], {Mouseover[{Red, #}, {Green, #}]}} & /@ {Disk[{0, 0}], 
    Text["Moi", {1.5, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}]}]
    (*Objects change color *)
```

When trying the same approach with Geographics

```
countries = {"Spain", "Belgium", "Romania"};
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Opacity[0.5]], 
  Mouseover[{Red, 
  Tooltip[Polygon[{Entity["Country", #]}], #]}, {Green, 
  Tooltip[Polygon[{Entity["Country", #]}], #]}]} & /@ countries]
```

Graphics are displayed but when mouse hovers on top of a country polygon, then an error message will toggle on the screen stating that "Coordinate Entity["Country","Spain"] should be a pair of numbers.....

What is the correct approach to make the polygon representing the country change colors when selected?

Comment: I can see it working since 10.1 (I cannot test with earlier versions). What was the version of the bug? I would like to write the bug header stating that the bug is fixed. If you prefer to do it, please feel free to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GeoGraphics` seems to have some fragility. I post this as a way (unfortunately not `Mouseover`) to achieve some interactivity:

```
{spain, belgium, romania} = countries;
h["Spain"] = spain; h["Belgium"] = belgium; h["Romania"] = romania;
g[x_] := {Blue, h[x]};
cnt = {"Spain", "Belgium", "Romania"};
f = DynamicModule[{col = Black},
    DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@Style[#, Bold, 20, col], 
     If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], col = Red; 
      g[#] = {Red, EdgeForm[Black], h[#]} , col = Black; 
      g[#] = {Blue, h[#]}]]] &;
Framed[Row[{Dynamic@
    GeoGraphics[g /@ cnt, ImageSize -> Large], 
   Column[f /@ {"Spain", "Belgium", "Romania"}]
```

[image]

This is a little unforgiving on my machine if I add options for the GeoGraphics object.

Just for variety (but do not run synchronously to avoid function definition conflicts):

```
f2 = DynamicModule[{col = Black},
    DynamicWrapper[Dynamic@Style[#, Bold, 20, col], 
     If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], col = Red; 
      g[#] = {GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], EdgeForm[Black], h[#]} , 
      col = Black; g[#] = {Blue, h[#]}]]] &;
Framed[Row[{Dynamic@
    GeoGraphics[g /@ cnt, ImageSize -> Large], 
   Column[f2 /@ {"Spain", "Belgium", "Romania"}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Let's try something more basic that doesn't require `GeoGraphics` to interpret entities:

```
countries = CountryData[#, "FullPolygon"] & /@ {Entity["Country", "Spain"], Entity["Country", "Belgium"], Entity["Country", "Romania"]};

GeoGraphics[{
  Mouseover[{Red, #}, {Blue, #}] & /@ countries
  }]
```

OK, it still doesn't work so it seems like it's a bug.

**Follow-up:** the WRI support has notified the development team about this.